# Column of Wordpress posts without white space above

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I built a blog under wordpress. I am searching for a way to display article like this :

[image: An image]

the php / html

```
                        <div id="uno">


                               <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a>
                                <?php the_excerpt();?>
                               <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Read more...</a>

                     </div>
```

and the css

```
#uno{width: 25%; height:100%; float:left; text-align:center; padding-top: 20px;}
```

Comment: use isotope or masonry

Comment: Ok, never used it. Let see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: using isotope.

css :

```
 .grid-image-item,
.grid--images .grid-sizer { width: 25%;}

.grid-image-item {
  float: left;
}

.grid-image-item img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

home.php :
load "isotope-docs.min.js" on the top of your page, juste bellow "get_header" using this

```
 <script src="where-you-placed-it/isotope-docs.min.js">
    </script>
```

```
  <div class="duo__cell example__demo">
    <div class="grid grid--images" data-js-module="imagesloaded-progress">
      <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

            <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
              <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                            <div class="grid-image-item">


                             <?php the_title(); ?>
                              <?php the_author() ?>

                              <?php the_time('j M Y') ?>
                              <?php the_category(', ') ?>
                              <?php the_excerpt();?>
                              <?php echo get_permalink(); ?>


                              </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to isotope/masonry => http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html

Comment: This should be comment or suggestion as link may be dead in future. Just a good advise from personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is your images are of different sizes so the gaps look different and because one image was larger then the others that's the primary gap for the following images.

One way I found that fixed this in my case was to navigate to your functions.php file and add this line of code in

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
add_image_size( 'myimage', 100, 100 );
```

change the `myimage` portion to what ever you like and the sizes that you would like your image to be fixed as.

After that you can then pull your image using `<?php the_post_thumbnail('myimage', array( 'class'   => "our-size")); ?>`

also just to be safe you could add some *css*.

```
.our-size {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
max-width: 100px;
max-height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But I'd like the article to have different height, maybe my image isn't clear, thanks anyway